# Adding mutual friend count to each user in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, facebook-graph-api

I have an array of Facebook users (userList) and I want to store the number of mutual friends for each user in the array as a property (mfCount). I have checked that I am getting the correct number of mutual friends if I put in an individual user, but I'm not sure why I can't add this value to each user in the array?

```
function getfriends() {
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
    userList = userList.concat(response.data);
    userCount = response.data.length;
    for( i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
      userId = response.data[i].id;
      FB.api('/me/mutualfriends/'+userId+'/', function(response) {
        userList[i].mfCount = response.data.length;
        userCount--;
        if(userCount === 0) { display_results();}
      });
    } 
  });
```

}

Comment: I think that if you build a simpler example, without using the FB API, it woul be easier to help you. Can you reproduce what you want but with an example without the API? I think that your problem is JavaScript, no the FB API. It's very difficult to help you without knowing what response have for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the implementation below.
I've broken it out into multiple functions to separate each step.
When you're dealing with loops and callbacks, it becomes very important to keep track of what scope your anonymous functions are being defined in.

You *can theoretically do it all in a one-liner* like you were writing...
...but it gets very, very confusing as you go further and further into nested-callbacks.

One solution would be to make every variable inside each function 100% global, so that only `i` needs to have an enclosed reference.  That's not really pretty, though.

Look through each function and take note of what parameters are going into the functions each step calls (or closures for callbacks).  They're all needed (whether you separate them this way, or through closures in a one-liner or whatever).

The following worked just fine for me, inside of the Facebook developer sandbox (first time using the API).
The logs were for my benefit to see how the data was coming out, and to keep a basic stack-trace.

```
var userList = [],
    userCount = 0;

function getfriends () {
    //console.log("getFriends");
    var url = "/me/friends";
    FB.api(url, function (response) {
        if (response.error && response.error.message) { return false; }
        userList = userList.concat(response.data);
        userCount = response.data.length;
        compareAllFriends();
    });
}

function compareAllFriends () {
    //console.log("compareAllFriends");
    var i = 0, l = userCount, userID;
    for (; i < l; i += 1) {
        userID = userList[i].id;
        compareFriendsWith (i, userID);
    }
}
function compareFriendsWith (i, id) {
    //console.log("compareFriendsWith", i, id);
    var path = "/me/mutualfriends/",
        url = path + id + "/";

    FB.api(url, (function (i) {
        return function (response) {
            //console.log(i, response);
            var numFriends = (response.data) ? response.data.length : 0;
            setMutualFriends(i, numFriends);
            userCount -= 1;
            //console.log(userCount);
            if (userCount === 0) {
                display_results();
                //console.log("DISPLAYING");
            }
        };
    }(i)));
}

function setMutualFriends (i, friendcount) { userList[i].mfCount = friendcount; }
```

Comment: I tried the code you suggest above, but it didn't seem to work. Here is the full function: `function getfriends() {
    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
        userList = userList.concat(response.data);
        userCount = response.data.length;
        for( i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
          userId = response.data[i].id;
          FB.api('/me/mutualfriends/'+userId+'/', function(response) {
            userList[i].mfCount = response.data.length;
            userCount--;
            if(guestCount === 0) { display_results();}
          });
        } 
      });
  }`

Comment: I added it to the original code above. I know that I am overwritting the variable userList - this is intentional as it is just an empty array set up to store the friend list (var userList = new Array();)

Comment: Have a look at the edited answer.  It should work for you (keeping in mind that it doesn't include `display_results` and it doesn't make the initial call to `getFriends`).

Comment: I tried your new code which successfully looped through compareFriendsWith for each friend, but then I got the following error for each friend: `Object
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined 
(anonymous function)
ka`

Comment: I also realized that my login code is looping through the getfriends function twice, but I don't think that is related to this issue so I created a separate thread: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11602687/facebook-login-auth-code-calling-loop-function-twice

Comment: Well, crap.  Two-part solution.  Inside of `compareWithFriends`, change the line `FB.api(url + id , ...` to `FB.api(url, ...` (remove the ` + id`).  Part two: before you set `response.data.<anything>`, check for `response.error` if it exists, then there won't be any `data` array, so `setMutualFriends` to 0 (so that you don't get `NaN` errors later in your script, if you're counting on `mfCount` to not be `undefined`.  Editing the code now.

Comment: That works now, thanks! Now I just need to figure out how to stop the auth function looping through the code twice.